# How do I fix layout differences for css box model among browsers?

Tags: css

I have a two column layout with a header. The Firefox view is off by a couple px on the flanks. It's fine in IE. I needed to insert divs to create padding under the header and the right side of the first column.

Comment: I also used a CSS reset.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally fought things like that so many times that I decided to move to using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).  Use their class naming conventions and I seriously doubt you will have any more column issues like that.  You will also have a mobile friendly layout... just a thought!

Here's an example of what two columns look like using Twitter Bootstrap.  The full width of the screen is divided into 12 segments.  Proportionally the first column is twice as wide as the second, that total of the numbers (8 and 4), must equal 12.  You can adjust them to your hear's content.

```
<div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
<div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Is a straightforward and short method. It's the same box model that Chrome Dev Tools uses to show you elements. Support, according to [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/), is

- Chrome (any): box-sizing
- Opera 8.5+: box-sizing
- Firefox (any): -moz-box-sizing
- Safari 3: -webkit-box-sizing (unprefixed in 5.1+ versions)
- IE8+: box-sizing

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility),

> The border-box rendering The width and height properties include the
>   padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by
>   Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode.

Note that some third party software, including Google Maps and Google Custom Search Engine, conflict may conflict with `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`, in these cases, you need to restore the element with:

```
.element {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Just as with Bootstrap's [third party support](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties).

### Considerations about performance

You can use the `.main > *` method, as recommended on [this blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/), if you're concerned about performance, but performance has gone up considerably in the last time.